# Protobuf extensions backward compatibility

Tags: protocol-buffers

I have a question about backward compatibility with protobuf and extensions. Lets say I have this message:

```
message A {
    required uint64 filed1 = 1;
    optional string field2 = 2;
}
```

Initially on the design we did not add the extensions property of the message but now we want to extend it and change it to something like this:

```
message A {
    required uint64 filed1 = 1;
    optional string field2 = 2;

    extensions 100 to max;
}
```

We want to add new messages that are extensions to this one but still want older clients to be able to read this base message.
My question is by adding these extensions at later point is this message still backward compatible?